# naming class methods in a consistent and precise way

Tags: oop, matlab

I wrote a simple tag manager class in matlab, and I'm struggling (or maybe over-thinking ;-) with naming my class methods appropriately. The class is called `tag_manager`. Here are my question regarding a clear API and implementation:

- for adding a tag, should I call the method `add` or `add_tag`? same goes for removing.
- for renaming a tag, should I call the method `rename_tag` or `rename`?

I always feel like adding the `_tag` suffix, so that it is clear what a method is acting upon.

- `nbr_tags` is a counter that keep track on the number of tags that are currently stored. I sometimes need to access this number, and so instead of going through the list of tags and calculating the number of entries, I thought to return this value through a class method.  Is `return_nbr_tags` the way to go, or could this be named more succinctly?
- Very often, I need to know the index of a tag, which is in turn used to look up some elements in some other matrix. In order to prevent code to become to long, I called this method simply `inx()` which is supposed to be an abbreviation for `return_tag_index`. I'm aware that today I do know what `inx()` stands for, but in two weeks from now I'll probably won't be able to remember. So what is the best way of naming these kind of methods?

here's the class definition:

```
properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = public)
    tag_names = {}; % store the tags
    tag_rel_indx = []; % the relative tag index
    tag_abs_indx = []; % the absolute tag index
end

properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = public, Hidden = true)
    nbr_tags = 0;
    abs_tag_counter = 0;
end

methods
    % add single tag to list. should be 'add' or 'add_tag'?
    function obj = add_tag(obj, name)
    end

    % remove single tag from list
    function obj = remove_tag(obj, name)
    end

    % short-cut for 'return_tag_index'
    function indx = inx(obj, name)
        indx = return_tag_index(obj, name);
    end

    % rename tag
    function obj = rename_tag(obj, old_name, new_name)
    end

    % re-order tags by name
    function obj = reorder_by_name(obj)
    end

    % return number of tags stored in tagmanager
    function nbr_tags = return_nbr_tags(obj)
        nbr_tags = obj.nbr_tags;
    end

end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is an excellent Matlab Style Guide by Richard Johnson
[link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46056-matlab-style-guidelines-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a trade-off between using highly explicit function names (which is really helpful to understand code) and creating code that's easy to develop and use. If you need to make shortcut names for methods, it's a sign that you have moved to far toward explicit function names.

In your case, since you're creating a tag manager, I would drop `tag` from the methods, and instead start the convention of instantiating your tag manager class as `tags = tagManager;`, such that the method of adding tags is written either `tags.add(...)` or `add(tags,...)`. Adding more explicit method names will help, though, when you're adding something other than tags, e.g. `tags.addGroup`. Your index method then becomes `index(tags,name)`, which is, in my eyes, both short and clear.

PS: Why have a `returnNumberOfTags` method? You can just read from the property, and add set/get methods if necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot! I could for sure just access `nbr_tags` directly, but I don't want the user to modify its value, so it's a private, hidden property. That's why I feel like I need to provide a visible API to it, i.e., using a `Get` or `Return` method.

Comment: @memyself: With setAccess set to private, it shouldn't be necessary to hide the property. But it's really a style issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, and having had to use other people's code before, I find it VERY helpful when the method/function names are clear and descriptive.  I'd much rather someone be verbose with the name of their function but at the same time you don't want to be overly verbose with it.

For instance your return number of tags function.  I would personally name that something like `GetNumberOfTags`.  For functions that I use to set a particular value I use `SetParticularValue`.

I do lean away from the underscores though.  That's probably most just a habit I picked up from the coding practices we have at work.

The biggest thing to remember is being consistent throughout the whole class.  AND don't forget to have useful comments if the function isn't entirely clear =P  It's horrible when you have to come back through and rework someone's code and there's a real dirth of information about what variables are being used for and what the function really is meant to do ;).